# Accessing environment vairables in quasar app

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm trying to access env variable but there is no way I can make it work:
I tried creating `.env` file and setting the variable

`VUE_APP_TOKEN: 11token22`

there but when I console.log it Im getting `undefined`.

Next thing I tried was setting the env variable in quasar.conf.js:

```
build: {
  vueRouterMode: 'hash', // available values: 'hash', 'history'
  env: {
    VUE_APP_TOKEN:'11token22' 
  },

  extendWebpack (cfg) {
    cfg.module.rules.push({
      enforce: 'pre',
      test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
      loader: 'eslint-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      options: {
        formatter: require('eslint').CLIEngine.getFormatter('stylish')
      }
    })
  }
},
```

And Im getting this error:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?5593:619 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: 11token22 is not defined"
```

In my component I just try to log `process.env`:

```
  mounted () {
      console.log(process.env);
  },
```

Any idea how can I access environment variable in quasar app? Im running out of ideas and in documentation I cant see anything that would help clarify this.

Im using quasar/cli 1.2 and quasar/app 1.0

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://dev.to/jotcomponents/how-use-env-files-in-quasar-1k55)?

Comment: Yes but it also does not work, I followed this and installed additional packages (qenv, crossenv, updated package.json with dev script) and I get this error when starting dev server: ` Quasar App Extension "@quasar/qenv" is missing...`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you've figured it out by now, but based on quasar [doc](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/handling-process-env), if you are using `.env` file, you can install the package first;

> yarn add --dev dotenv

or

> npm install dotenv --save

then, in `/quasar.config.js`;

```
build: {
  env: require('dotenv').config().parsed
}
```

then you can access with `process.env.<YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE>`, and according to the docs, `console.log(process.env)` will error, while `process.env.<YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE>` will resolve

> Do not console.log(process) or console.log(process.env) as this will error out, for security reasons.

Comment: Works magically. Saved me a lot of time. I'd been through a million guides and none was working for such a basic thing and they were too complicated.